What are some good examples of templates for creating issues and MRs in Gitlab/Github
I wanted to standardise the issues and MRs across all my apps and repos. So, I am in the quest of finding the most descriptive issue & MR template.
Although, this changes based on the requirements of the issue and MR. But, I just want to explore the possibilities.
I have been looking online, but I thought it's better to ask the developers
Currently I am having this as MR Template
Have you done the following:
- [ ] Have you squashed your commits?
- [ ] Does your squashed commit have a tag like [FIX],[MAINTENANCE],[FEATURE],[CLEANUP],[UPGRADE]
- [ ] Did you write new test cases for this merge request?
- [ ] Did the test cases run successfully in your environment?

##### Explain the problem 
---



##### Explain the solution 
---



##### Provide links to any relevant issue tickets, articles or other resources
---


And using this as my Issue Template
### Description
---


### User Story
---


### Acceptance Criteria
---


### Implementation Notes
---


### Testing Notes
---


### Dependencies
---


### Resources
---




You can find examples of issue and merge request templates directly on the GitLab project:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/tree/master/.gitlab?ref_type=heads
Yours are already quite good. What might be missing are possibly labels or other quick actions (/cc to identify a responsible person or to directly assign someone, etc.).
I hope this has been helpful.
